google.generativeai.types.generation_types.IncompleteIterationError
I got this error:
Traceback:
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 584, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/mount/src/multimodal-image2story-app/1_Main.py", line 372, in <module>
    main()
File "/mount/src/multimodal-image2story-app/1_Main.py", line 366, in main
    with tab1: TabInput(gemini_api_key).create_tab_input()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/mount/src/multimodal-image2story-app/1_Main.py", line 316, in create_tab_input
    with col_generate_button: self.generate_story_button()
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/mount/src/multimodal-image2story-app/1_Main.py", line 283, in generate_story_button
    Model(self.gemini_api_key).generate_story_from_image()
File "/mount/src/multimodal-image2story-app/1_Main.py", line 123, in generate_story_from_image
    st.session_state.story_results.append(response.text)
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/generativeai/types/generation_types.py", line 354, in text
    parts = self.parts
            ^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/generativeai/types/generation_types.py", line 332, in parts
    candidates = self.candidates
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/generativeai/types/generation_types.py", line 322, in candidates
    raise IncompleteIterationError(_INCOMPLETE_ITERATION_MESSAGE)

Here's my function that got error:
def generate_story_from_image(self) -> list[str]:
                '''Generate story using input image, last stories (if exist), input other text'''
                # Execute prompt function
                self.prompt()
                model = self.configuration()
                text_prompt = str(st.session_state.model_prompt)
                # text_prompt = "Buatkan cerita dari gambar ini!"
                image = st.session_state.uploaded_image
                response = model.generate_content([text_prompt, image], stream = True)
                with st.spinner('Wait...'): # Add loading screen
                        time.sleep(20) # wait 20 second
                st.session_state.story_results.append(response.text) <--- Error on this line

can anyone explain why i got this error? I use google.generativeai and streamlit framework
I expect the code is not error and the result could be possible

(If you are checking this post in Sep 2024)
A lot of things got changed over these past months. If you want to use streamlit and Gemini try checking https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-build-a-chat-web-application-with-streamlit-cloud-run-and-gemini-flash-8eb1ac55b201 (Uploading images could be trying + I have not tried that)
JLYK. Google Cloud Gemini - Python SDK has a Chat feature which internally maintains a ChatSession. Try digging into it. Here is a some code to kick start - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/main/generative_ai/chat.py

As for IncompleteIterationError if you think error is in st.session_state.story_results.append(response.text) , try check the type(story_results) and type(response.text);
But I believe the error is in response = model.generate_content([text_prompt, image], stream = True) , where you are updating the image. Here is a good example of how to add images to Gemini Prompt - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/main/generative_ai/gemini_multi_image_example.py
